# Would annotating a setter with @PreAuthorize be too brutal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a certain entity that can possibly be edited by different actors. A good example for the scenario would be an user of a system, who can edit their personal data (phone no, e-mail, password), but cannot modify e.g. their privileges or username, which could of course be done by a super-user.

So, would it be too brutal and ugly if I just annotated the setter methods with @PreAuthorize? The only disadvantage I could think of is the performance loss, but since there are no bulk operations involving the entity I am thinking of and those setters will never be called often it doesn't seem like a concern now.

Comment: The question is given a perfectly good answer by Bozho - it is YES, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't advise for that. First, if I see things properly, `@PreAuthorize` requires a class to be a bean. And generally, entities are not spring beans (unless you use the `@Configurable` magic). So it just won't work.

Second, the better place for `@PreAuthorize` is on the business methods that perform the modifications.

Comment: You seem right, plus after some thought I know I won't do it this way. The problem is that, in my case, the business-methods are just responsible for the CRUD part and the binding of the request parameters to the entity (DTO) properties happens within a framework (Spring MVC in my case). So far I have been unsuccessful in devising a way to stop the framework from binding some properties.

Comment: That is an interesting question. I guess you can try making some customizations in the Binder - what to bind and what not, but it may not be straighforward (I don't know if there is binder-configuration-per-request).

Comment: It would actually be quite straightforward - just one @InitBinder annotated method where the default PropertyEditors are substituted by authorization-aware ones. Thanks for the tip !